# Close one tab in chrome using C#

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome

I can close all tab in chrome by use process thus:

```
Process[] chromeInstances = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
if (chromeInstances.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (Process p in chromeInstances)
    {
        p.Kill(); ;
    }
}
```

But I want close one tab in chrome. It is possible?

Comment: does it matter which one you close?  As you could just exit the loop after 1 go around.

Comment: take a look here for a similar question asked by a different individual http://superuser.com/questions/306714/how-to-kill-one-tab-of-google-chrome-using-pid

Comment: Why would you want to close an arbitrary control element in an arbitrary user process? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

According to this post, it is not possible: https://superuser.com/a/306715/68020

> You can't close a tab by killing the process. The process represents a renderer that the main browser uses the execute and draw a page, which it then copies to the screen. The "Aw, Snap!" is what the browser displays when the renderer responsible for that tab crashes or is killed. The proper way to close the tab would ideally be via a command-line switch, but there is none that I know of at this time.

Also, as the comment describes,

> [there isn't a 1:1 relationship between tabs and renderer processes in the first place.](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/process-models)

Comment: There are other ways?

Comment: you would have to see if there's a windows API for chrome that you could hook into. you could look at the chromium source code to see how to close a tab